# installing an app through the terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, package-management, pop-os

i'm brand new to Linux coming from Windows so everything is confusing for me at the moment.

I run currently "Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS" and trying to install this VPN called Private VPN (https://privatevpn.com/support/getting-started/linux/linux/network-manager-tun-recommended).

On the website it tells me to install use the terminal with using either:
sudo apt-get install -y network-manager-openvpn
or
sudo apt-get -y install network-manager-openvpn-gnome

Although I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
network-manager-openvpn-gnome is already the newest version (1.8.18-1).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  nvidia-firmware-545-545.29.02
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

or

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
network-manager-openvpn-gnome is already the newest version (1.8.18-1).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  nvidia-firmware-545-545.29.02
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Is the problem that I don´t have Ubuntu or am I missing something? Any other way to get Private VPN working on my system (I payed already a yearly subscription... so prefer not to switch VPN's unless I have to)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The required packages are already installed, so you should be able to continue the setup process from step 5.

Comment: Thanks I didn´t know it went that fast. Indeed I could already proceed to the next step! It's a bit less clear then I am used to ^^